# Running of gravitational constant versus. other coupling constants, GUT and TOE

Tags: renormalization, physical-constants, theory-of-everything, grand-unification

Is there any theory that proves convincingly that the gravitational constant runs with energy AND it is like the other coupling constants and converge at a single point at a given energy? Or is that a theory and hypothesis made by extrapolation and GUT extended to a TOE? That is, how much do we know about the running gravitational constant from general relativity, LQG, asymptotically safe gravity and/or string theories?

Comment: Your questions make no sense.  The gravitational constant does not need energy and it does not "run" anywhere!